# How to fix a GitHub repo inside of another and that is hiding files from the "higher" repo?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

My directory structure looks like this:

```
/School
    /Freshman
        /Class
        /Class
        /Class
        ...
    /Sophomore
        /AI
            /SearchAlgorithms
        /Class
        /Class
        ...
```

`School` is a GitHub repo that I use for myself so that I can access all of my files from multiple computers/virtual machines. `SearchAlgorithms` is another repo I created for my AI class because I have to work on a coding project with someone else in my class. I successfully shared the `SearchAlgorithms` repo with him and I have no issues. However the files in that repo are not 'visible' to my `School` repo, and whenever I make a commit in `SearchAlgorithms` a modified "file" shows up in my School repo that looks like this:

[image]

I use SourceTree for repo management, but trying to use the command line instead didn't change anything.

How do I make the files inside of `SearchAlgorithms` visible and available to `School`? I don't particularly want to have to clone `SearchAlgorithms` to every computer I work on, and just rely on my laptop to do pushes for that repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+make+one+repository+subdirectory+another